# Adding dynamically user control to a Asp Table

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, user-controls, celltable

I'm trying to add dynamically an **input checkbox type** and a **asp textbox** to a Asp Tablecell, using some data from a dataset. I've read few post about this but none has the combination want to reach.

This is the code I'm using (Where *ds* is the dataset and *tblMeasuredChar* is the Asp Table):

```
   If ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then

        For Each dr As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows
            Dim tr As New TableRow()

            'defining input
            Dim tc As New TableCell()
            tc.Text = "<input type=" & Chr(34) & "checkbox" & Chr(34) & " name=" & Chr(34) & "chkMeasuredChars" & Chr(34) & " value=" & Chr(34) & dr("id") & Chr(34) & "/>" & dr("description")

            'defining unique textbox
            Dim txtbx As New TextBox()
            txtbx.ID = "tbMeasuredChars" & dr("id")
            'add it to the cell
            tc.Controls.Add(txtbx)

            'add the cell to the row
            tr.Controls.Add(tc)

            tblMeasuredChar.Rows.Add(tr)
        Next
    End If
```

The problem is that just the last "thing" that I add to the TableRow is shown. I must use an input of this type, it couldn't be possible to use some asp checkbox. Is it possible to add an user control to a TableCell that already have some text other text?

I've already tried to add the TableCell like *tr.Cells.Add(tc)* and some other combintations but the result still the same. Adding the control to the cell makes the checkbox (and everything early defined) disappear.

Thank you all.

Comment: Your life would be much easier if you did this using a `Repeater`. Let me know if you would like to explore this option and I would be happy to give you an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a [`Literal` control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.literalcontrol.aspx?), rather than using the `.Text` property.  Like this:

```
If ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then

    For Each dr As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows
        Dim tr As New TableRow()

        'defining input
        Dim tc As New TableCell()
        tc.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("<input type=" & Chr(34) & "checkbox" & Chr(34) & " name=" & Chr(34) & "chkMeasuredChars" & Chr(34) & " value=" & Chr(34) & dr("id") & Chr(34) & "/>" & dr("description")))

        'defining unique textbox
        Dim txtbx As New TextBox()
        txtbx.ID = "tbMeasuredChars" & dr("id")
        'add it to the cell
        tc.Controls.Add(txtbx)

        'add the cell to the row
        tr.Controls.Add(tc)

        tblMeasuredChar.Rows.Add(tr)
    Next
End If
```

It sounds like this would meet your needs nicely, as it's not like a normal ASP.NET serv control, it's basically just static HTML text.  From the documentation linked above:

> ASP.NET compiles all HTML elements and readable text that do not
>   require server-side processing into instances of this class. For
>   example, an HTML element that does not contain a runat="server"
>   attribute/value pair in its opening tag is compiled into a
>   LiteralControl object.

So your text is basically being compiled into a Literal control already.  I think this will just solve the display issue you're having, with using both the `.Text` property and the `.Controls` collection.

Comment: Thank you jadarnel, it worked like a charm! And many thanks, not just for the answer but for the explanation too.

Comment: @weilah I'm very glad I could help =)